# Проблема с выводом через foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Суть проблемы такова, делаю запрос к базе:

```
$base = $db->row("SELECT * FROM `base` WHERE uid` = ? AND `delete` = '0' ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 50", Array($_SESSION['id']));
```

Далее получаю 3 строки из базы, хочу вывести через метод foreach:

```
foreach ($base as $value) {

            $json['akk'][] = Array($value['id'], $value['login']);

        }
```

Но когда происходит вывод, он выводит не id, login, а [image: Ошибка кода]

Comment: Что выводит `print_r($base);` ?

Comment: @newman, Вывело Array

Comment: странно. должно бы вывести и его содержимое. Кстати, что это за класс такой для работы с базой?

Comment: какая библиотека для mysql используется?

Comment: @newman, вывело Array ( [id] => 1 [uid] => 1 [rang] => 23 [login] => lol123 [password] => lol123 [email] => lol123@lol123.ru [pass_email] => lol123 [premium] => 1 [marker] => [delete] => 0 )

Comment: PDO использую...

Comment: @inf1 это всего одна запись, а вы говорите выводится три

Comment: у pdo разве есть метод `row()`?

Comment: @mix, это уже класс

Comment: ну так!? о нем и идет речь. какой класс используется?

Comment: @mix, я вывел не через foreach, а просто

Comment: имя метода `row` - как бы говорит о том, что он сделает выборку только одной строки из базы. Для данной задачи нужен метод навроде `rows`, `fetchAll`  или тому подобное, что есть в используемом классе.

Comment: @newman, вот, теперь вывело все 3 строки

Comment: Только вот как это всё в foreach превратить, чтобы выводило?

Comment: @inf1 результат какого вида вы ожидаете получить?

Comment: Хочу получать именно строки id, login и далее выводить их в json виде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, вы планируете вывести данные в таком формате:

```
foreach ($base as $value) {
    $item['id'] = $value['id'];
    $item['login'] = $value['login'];
    $json['akk'][] = $item;
}
```

или же как вы написали, но с поправкой:

```
foreach ($base as $value) {
    $json['akk'][] = array('id' => $value['id'], 'login' => $value['login']);
}
```